# Matlab coder - mex out of a function receiving 2 dimensional matrix of double - how to specify dynamic size?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

My matlab function goes something like this:

```
    function out=func(M)
    for i=1:size(M,2)
        do something on M(:,i)..
    end
```

How Can I tell matlab coder that parameter M is of dynamic dimensions.
I only see options like: 
assert(isa(M, 'double'));
or asserting M to have constant dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Matlab's coder documentation at http://www.mathworks.it/help/toolbox/coder/ug/bsxyt0_.html